# Automatically rewrite git history for open source release

Tags: git, open-source, release, code-analysis, revision-history

I'm currently releasing several projects as open source. Typically the complete source is provided as ZIP archive or checked in at an open source repo. This makes analysis by [ohloh](https://www.ohloh.net/) difficult.

In case the software has been developed in a non-public repository, the complete history is available. However, I do not want to have the full history released.

I want to use git for reaching one of the two possibilites:

**(i) One commit per author:**
There should be one commit per author (with the commit date the final release date). Each commit contains the lines of code, which finally made it into the final version.

**(ii) Original commits with only the final code lines:** In this variant, the number of commits itself are preserved. Each commit is modified in a way that only the lines, which finally made it into the final version, are preserved and all other ones are deleted.

Has anyone implemented one of the variants yet? Variant (i) seems to be doable using [git-blame](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-blame.html) and some scripting.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why this approach?  Is this essentially a subset of your full, private repository.

Comment: Privacy reasons. I promised the committers that their commits won't be available in the public. Mostly, they are students learning coding. I don't want to have their mistakes and working hours available in public. - Do you remember CrossPoint (fidonet software?) There, it was possible to set the mail creation time to "00:00" to offer a bit of privacy :)

Comment: Google's [Copybara](https://github.com/google/copybara) and it's predecessor [MOE](https://github.com/google/moe) seem to have similar goals. They even allow to synchronize private and public repositories. Further investigation is needed whether they really can provide the same functionalities.

Comment: (Disclaimer, I am a Google engineer working on Copybara). Copybara should do what you want. It is able to filter commits using origin_files and also scrub information from commit message or files (We don't recommend this so that the migration is reversible and you are able to import Pull Requests from your external contributors). We also support several kind of transformations. Mode i) is what we call SQUASH mode and MODE ii) ITERATIVE. CHANGE_REQUEST is the mode that allows to import back contributions from non-source of truth repositories (someone sends you a pull request to the public repo)

Comment: @Mikel Thank you for your comment. After working on git-oss-releaser, I found both [Copybara](https://github.com/google/copybara) and its predecessor [MOE](https://github.com/google/moe). I put it into the README.md as related projects: https://github.com/koppor/git-oss-releaser#related-projects. I was so free to include your comment in the README.md. I hope, this is OK for you!

Comment: yeah, that sounds good :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[git-oss-releaser](https://github.com/koppor/git-oss-releaser) is a solution for option (i).

git-oss-releaser converts a given git repository to a git repository only containing the files of the last commit and commits resembling `git blame` output for each file.
The original history is lost.

usage: `git-oss-releaser.py [-h] repoDir outDir`

Positional arguments:

- `repoDir`: The repository to transform. May also be a subdirectory of a repo.
- `outDir`: The directory where the new repo should be created. Has to be empty.

Optional arguments:

- `--name NAME`    The `user.name` to use for *committing* the files. Defaults to git's global `user.name`.
- `--email EMAIL`  The `user.email` to use for *committing* the files. Defaults to git's global `user.email`.
- `--date DATE`    The date to use for commits. Defaults to the date the last commit.

Note that git distinguishes author and committer at a commit.
The author is taken using `git blame`, the committer data is taken from the global `user.name` and `user.email`or the given configured `--name` and `--email`.

DEBUG mode can currently only be enabled in the code.

### Limitations

- Works on git repositories without any untracked files only
- Empty lines are assigned to "git-oss-releaser" and not the first or last author adding these empty lines
- Repository has to contain at least one non-binary file
- Commit date is derived from non-binary files only
- Tested under [git for windows](https://git-for-windows.github.io/) only

Comment: @downvoters: Please explain why you downvote my answer. - I extended it now to be more self-contained.

Answer (score 2):

**(i) One commit per author**

I guess that's logically not possible: Suppose you've got a sequence of commits like this:

- Commit: A, Author: Alpha
- Commit: B, Author: Beta
- Commit: C, Author: Alpha

If commit C depends on anything done in B, you cannot reorder and squash A and C anymore.

**(ii) Original commits with only the final code lines**

For that you can use 'git filter-branch --tree-filter'. Beware that the following script might eat kittens, because I've only tested it on a simple test repository. You've been warned:

```
git filter-branch --prune-empty --tree-filter '
    # directory which contains the final version of the project
    FINAL_VERSION="$DIRECTORY_WITH_REPOSITORY_OF_FINAL_VERSION"

    # directory which contains the filtered version of the repository
    FILTER_DIR="$(pwd)"

    # apply the current commit in to the final version in reverse mode,
    # ignore the rejects
    cd "$FINAL_VERSION"
    git show "$GIT_COMMIT" > /tmp/original.patch
    cat /tmp/original.patch | patch -p1 -t
    git diff > /tmp/filtered.patch

    # reset the FINAL_VERSION to the original state.
    git reset --hard
    git clean -f -d -x

    # apply the patch which contains the lines which could be reversed on
    # the filtered version
    cd "$FILTER_DIR"
    # revert the last commit
    patch -p1 -t < /tmp/original.patch

    # apply the filtered patch
    patch -p1 -t < /tmp/filtered.patch
    # remove the rejects by the modified patch 
    find -name "*.orig" -o -name "*.rej" | xargs rm -rf
' previousRelease..HEAD
```

(this assumes that you've tagged the branching point with "previousRelease". you also have to adapt the FINAL_VERSION variable.)